# How to show Vimeo Pro Private Video's in a jQuery Mobile App

Tags: vimeo-api

So I have an app that I am developing using jQM, it will be for iOS and Android. We have some videos on Vimeo Pro that are private with embed disabled except for specific domain names. I am trying to get these videos to work in the app but of course they say it cant be played due to its privacy settings.

Is there a way to use the API to play these videos?

I have tried to read through the Vimeo API but to be honest, it's very confusing and not very helpful.

Comment: can you please provide an example of what you've done so far ?

Comment: I have tried the oEmbed JS code but that doesn't help, and I can't make heads or tails of the API documentation. So Unfortunately have nothing to show as an example

Answer (score 0):

**1. Get an access token**

I assume you are only showing your own videos. You should start out by reading up on Vimeo's Single User authentication flow: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#single-user.

The short description is 1. Create an app: https://developer.vimeo.com/apps. 2. Generate an access token on your app page. 3. Hard code that token into your app (preferably into a configuration file)

**2. Get your videos**

Now that you have an access token, make an HTTP GET request to https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos with your access token in the Authorization header: `Authorization: bearer <token>`.

The response will contain up to 25 videos owned by the authenticated user. If you need more than 25, you need to make additional requests. You can learn more with the pagination docs: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#pagination but the short version is that instead of https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos, the new page's url is under the "next" key.

**3. Get your embed codes**

Embed codes are currently generated through oEmbed. You can read our docs here: https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed. But the short version is you make an additional HTTP request to `http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=<vimeo_url>` where vimeo_url is the "link" field in the response from step #2.